# How to get notified when the system date changes in an UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

My question seems a fairly simple one, but after hours of searching I found nothing that could solve my problem.

I am developing a calendar app and I need to keep it up to date so it would always show the current day correctly. The case I can't solve is when the user changes the system date manually.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295235/getting-notified-when-the-datetime-changes-in-c-sharp) and [SystemEvent.TimeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the exact thing I am looking for. Sadly, it's not present in UWP. Is there a substitute of any kind for it?

I also stumbled upon the TimeZoneChange value of [SystemTriggerType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx), but I tested it with the [background task sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) and it only works when the system time changes due to time zone change (as the documentation states). It's nice and it's close to my problem, but clearly not a sufficient solution.

Comment: If your app runs in the foreground, it seems like a simple thing to do with a timer. However, if your app runs is suspended, there's no way to achieve this. The BackgroundTask does not support TimeChanged SystemTrigger, which seems too costy for a background task.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I thought about it too, but it's not the exact problem I am facing. I updated my question to be more accurate.

Comment: Is it really a common use case that users are changing the system date/time settings on their machine while your app is open? This seems like more of a theoretical requirement than an actual need for someone with a calendar app. If users really are doing this a lot have you investigated why? It may be a workaround for some other issue that you may be better able to solve another way.

Comment: No Matt, you are right, it's not a very likely use case. I'd just like to be prepared for everything, that's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Will the [TimeTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) class be helpful for you in this instance?

Comment: " Note that your app must be placed on the lock screen, and the background task must be declared in the manifest, before the registration can be successful."

Comment: Yep, as Chris says. Sorry, it's really not what I am looking for.

Comment: Actually, [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186458.aspx) says that "Starting with Windows 10, it is no longer necessary for the user to add your app to the lock screen in order to utilize background tasks".

Comment: Hah, right! Still not exactly what I am looking for, I stumbled upon this myself too while searching.